# Excel VBA Prevent workbook save when clicking X

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create macro which will not allow the workbook user to save the workbook if there are cell errors such as #VALUE!. I've written this:

```
      Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
          Dim rng As Range
          Dim c As Range
          Dim a As Variant
          
          Set rng= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C10")
          
          For Each c In rng
              If IsError(c.Value) Then
                  a = MsgBox(Prompt:="Check cells for #VALUE! and correct them before saving.", Title:="Check Cells")
                  Cancel = True
                  Exit For
              End If
          Next 
      End Sub
```

This works well when the user clicks the save button, but I'm running into issues when the click X and then hit save. When this happens, the macro above still runs, but once they click Ok on the message box that tells them they can't save, the close workbook event continues and the workbook closes. This is not the behavior desired behavior.

Behavior I want (assuming sheet has errors):

1. User clicks X and the Save. The workbooks has errors, so it's not allowed to save. The workbook stays open
2. User clicks X and then Do Not Save. The workbook closes as normal.

Comment: Please share what `cancelClose = True` is all about?

Comment: @VBasic2008 `cancelClose = True` was me starting to experiment with figuring out how to solve the problem before I asked here. It can be ignored and I've removed it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your `Workbook_BeforeSave` event, you should make a `Workbook_BeforeClose` event. Check the cells for errors, display your message if needed, and then cancel the close event, preventing the user from exiting until they have corrected the errors. When the close event is cancelled, the pop-up asking to save the workbook does not appear.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim a As Variant
    
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C10")
    
    For Each c In rng
        If IsError(c.Value) Then
            a = MsgBox(Prompt:="Check cells for #VALUE! and correct them before saving.", Title:="Check Cells")
            Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If you want the user to still be able to close, but not save, if the workbook has errors. Then display a YesNo msgbox and ask the user if they want to close without saving.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim a As Variant
    
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C10")
    
    For Each c In rng
        If IsError(c.Value) Then
            a = MsgBox(Prompt:="Check cells for #VALUE! and correct them before saving.", Title:="Check Cells")
            If MsgBox("Close without saving?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            Else
                Cancel = True
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This kind of works. The workbook closes, but some sort of Excel gray Excel application window and the VBA window remain open.

Comment: @user3752138 So the workbook closes, but the Application stays open. This makes sense since we didn't tell the application to close. The command you're looking for is something like `If Application.Workbooks.Count = 0 Then Application.Quit`. But there is a problem. This script cannot continue sending commands after the workbook has closed, and it causes an error when trying to close the application before the workbook. I'm a bit stuck on how to add that as a feature, and I'm out of free-time in my workday. Maybe you can find help elsewhere or in another post. Good Luck!